# PHP to XMLHttpRequest SQL Delete

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I have a table that is populated using AJAX show on a webpage and am able to generate it live from database results, with this though I want to make more of a friendly web front-end and be able to delete from the database, but I want something that will live update, and am wondering how I can turn something like this

```
<a href="hostRemove.php?host=10.72.0.154">Delete</a>
```

Into an XMLHttpRequest Delete.
The way the above works is by adding that unique IP to the URL then the PHP grabs it and refers it back to the database to then to delete it.

I know the above method is unsafe but it's for a college project to show we can do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem? You've recognised that you need to use XHR (well, you could use fetch instead). Is the XHR documentation unclear? Do you have some other problem?

Comment: Well you should not be using GET request. An Ajax delete request would be the best thing,

Comment: Quentin, I don't understand how to pass that data through to refer it back to the database? Thats what I need help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a "click" eventlistener to the hyperlink element, which executes a function where you send an XMLHttpRequest to your hostRemove.php
- Have that php script return some value(s), that you check in your XMLHttpRequest's OnReadyStateChanged callback function, and to which you react appropriately (by deleting the concerning row through DOM manipulation, showing an error message if failed, ...).
- Don't forget to catch the event when you define eventlistener's function, and call PreventDefault on it. Alternatively, you could use a button instead of a hyperlink.